# Excel Macro to create formula works fine. Macro to copy and paste formula leaves #Values

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a User Defined function to get the color of a cell.

```
Function GetFillColor(Rng As Range) As Long
    GetFillColor = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

The Function works.

I wrote a macro to use the function on a spreadsheet:

```
    Sub Macro5()

     Macro5 Macro                 
        Windows("KobeCurrent2.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Direct").Select
        Range("AP2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NUMBERVALUE(GetFillColor(RC[-26]))"
        Range("AP2").Select
        Dim LR As Long
     LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("AP2").Select
    Range("AP2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AP2:AP" & LR)

End Sub
```

Cell AP2 shows the value of the color of the cell.
The rest of the cells in column AP show #Value!
Until I double click on the #Value!, then it changes to the value of the color of the cell.

I tried multiplying the cells by 1, Using Data Text to columns, but when executing via excel macro I still get #Value! and it still requires a double click to resolve.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to be careful with UDFs that are dependent on the non-value aspects of a Range.  In particular, here, you probably just need to force a recalculation in order to get the update.  This is most easily done with `CTRL+ALT+F9` which will update all of the cells.  In general, the Excel VBA interaction does not support updating references when non-value changes occur.  So, update the cell color, the formula will not fire for dependent cells since Excel doesn't count that as a change.  To handle this, you typically mark a UDF as `Application.Volatile` as the first line of the UDF.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your script, but I got #NAME errors, so I modified it to place the values in AP2 etc, rather than the formula. This may not be what you're looking for, but easily modified. Hope this helps or gets you headed in the right direction.

```
Sub Macro5() ' ' Macro5 Macro '

Dim LR As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count


Windows("KobeCurrent2.xlsm").Activate

For x = 2 To LR Step 1

    Range("AP" & x).Value = Range("A" & x).Interior.ColorIndex

Next x
 ' I left these in here for reference.
 'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=GetFillColor(RC[-15])"    
 'Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & LR)
End Sub
```

Comment: This certainly solves the problem of getting the `ColorIndex` into a cell, but does not explain why the UDF fails initially.

Comment: @Byron Wall you are certainly correct, and why it fails is way beyond my scope of comprehension, so I just side stepped the issue for a "workable" solution. I believe most good programmers would call it a "hack". Guilty as charged :)